What do you call a big piece of paper with a list of plays for the month?

On the wall near the entrance to the theater hangs a big sheet of paper (approximately 600×800 mm in size) with a list of current performances. Should it be called a playbill, an events poster, a program poster or something else? Is there a difference in what it is called in different parts of the US, Canada and the UK?
P.S. In my language, this kind of sheets with information about upcoming performances have a different name than those used for propaganda or advertising. I'm having trouble understanding if this distinction exists in English as well.

US: Posters are large and posted outside. Theater programs are booklets with details of the event on stage now. "Playbill" is a trademarked brand name of a program.

@YosefBaskin Really? I see that proper-noun Playbill is a magazine, but that there's also a common-noun playbill that advertises a play, as well as one synonymous with "program." The advertising poster kind doesn't necessarily contain a full season, but seems to me it could.

The Playbill program on Broadway calls itself a magazine for its ads and an article or two. Theatergoers would never subscribe to a theater program they get free from the usher seating them.

event calendar .

In UK it's a poster regardless of its actual content. A playbill is more of a leaflet, and a hoarding or billboard is huge.

I would call this a "calendar" or a "calendar of events".
